# How to populate a listview edit text with previously added values?

Tags: java, android, listview

In my `main activity`, I'm using a `dialog` to show a `listview` on clicking a button, the `listview` contains three `textview`, one `edittext` and one done `button`. By clicking the done `button` I'm showing only those rows which contain values in `edittext` using loop in a `linear layout` in my `main activity`, now what I want is that when I'll again reopen the `dialog` for list the `edittext` field will contain those values which have previously been added. How can I do that?

This is the code for populating the `listview` in the `dialog`,

```
allProducts = dh.gettAllProductInfo();
adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), allProductss);
            productListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is when done `button` is clicked...

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ArrayList<productinfo> AddedItems = new ArrayList<productinfo>();
                    try
                    {
                    for(int i = 0;i<allProductss.size();i++)
                    {   

                        View view = productListView.getChildAt(i);
                        EditText qty = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_edittext);
                        String qtyVal = qty.getText().toString();
                        TextView product = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_textview);
                        String pName = product.getText().toString();
                        TextView p_code = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_code);
                        String pCode = p_code.getText().toString();

                        if(qty.getText().toString().matches(""))
                        {
                            //Do nothing
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AddedItems.add(new productinfo(pCode, pName, "", qtyVal, ""));
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: basically u wanna restore listview items?

Comment: yes.....the whole list items with edit text values....

Comment: keep the items in arraylist and save it , save it vai either shared-pref or pass as bundle to activity

Comment: any example will be helpful..................

Comment: there is no example as such i know but basically idea is store the arraylist which u pass in adapter save as json in shared pref and restore again arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to make an example based on what I've understood what you want. Moreover, you'll need to adapt it to your code works. This is the example:

```
private ArrayList<productinfo> AddedItems;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // you have to put this part of code when you show the dialog so that 
    // it will be executed all the time you open the dialog 
    if(AddedItems != null){

        allProducts.addAll(AddedItems);

        AddedItems = null;

    }
    else{

        allProducts = dh.gettAllProductInfo();

    }

    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), allProductss);

    productListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AddedItems = new ArrayList<productinfo>();          

            try
            {

                for(int i = 0;i<allProductss.size();i++)
                {   

                    View view = productListView.getChildAt(i);
                    EditText qty = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_edittext);
                    String qtyVal = qty.getText().toString();
                    TextView product = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_textview);
                    String pName = product.getText().toString();
                    TextView p_code = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_code);
                    String pCode = p_code.getText().toString();

                    if(!qty.getText().toString().matches(""))
                    {
                        AddedItems.add(new productinfo(pCode, pName, "", qtyVal, ""));
                    }

                }
            }   
            catch(Exception e){}

        }

    }

}
```